# Count the number of days per month between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two inputs type date and one input type text.

When I pick two dates I would like to know how many dates are picked between per month.

Example:

first-date: 28.08.2020.

last-date: 3.09.2020.

Result: 4 days in 08. month and 3 days in 09. month

What I have right now is script that counts the number of days between two dates

```js
function GetDays() {
  var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("dep").value);
  var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("arr").value);
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal() {
  if (document.getElementById("dep")) {
    document.getElementById("number-of-dates").value = GetDays();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input id="arr" type="date" name="arr" onchange="cal()">
  <input id="dep" type="date" name="dep" onchange="cal()">
  <input id="number-of-dates" type="text">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/768qrhz3/1/

Comment: I'm unsure of what your actual question is?  What is wrong with what you already have?

Comment: If I pick two dates and they are between two months  I would like to know how many days are selected per month in that range. 

Example dates picked: from 28.08.2020.to 3.09.2020.)

Result: 4 days in 08. month and 3 days in 09. month

Comment: So go determine the number of days from the start date to the last day of that month, and from the first of the last month to the end date … For any month in between, it’s just the full number of days that month has. The only edge case you have to check for upfront is when both dates are in the same month.

Comment: Can you give me code example? I don't know how to write that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You get the days per month even for leap years like february 2020.

```js
function getDays() {
    var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("arr").value);
    var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("dep").value);
    var result = "";
    for (var year = dropdt.getFullYear(); year <= pickdt.getFullYear(); year++) {
        var firstMonth = (year == dropdt.getFullYear()) ? dropdt.getMonth() : 0;
        var lastMonth = (year == pickdt.getFullYear()) ? pickdt.getMonth() : 11;
        for (var month = firstMonth; month <= lastMonth; month++) {
            var firstDay = (year === dropdt.getFullYear() && month === firstMonth) ? dropdt.getDate() : 1;
            var lastDay = (year === pickdt.getFullYear() && month === lastMonth) ? pickdt.getDate() : 0;
            var lastDateMonth = (lastDay === 0) ? (month + 1) : month
            var firstDate = new Date(year, month, firstDay);
            var lastDate = new Date(year, lastDateMonth, lastDay);
            result += (month + 1) + " - " + parseInt((lastDate - firstDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000) + 1) + "; ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function cal() {
    if (document.getElementById("dep")) {
        document.getElementById("number-of-dates").value = getDays();
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input id="arr" type="date" name="arr" value="2019-09-15"> 
  <input id="dep" type="date" name="dep" value="2020-03-15">
  <button onclick="cal()">Calculate</button>
  <input style="width:400px" id="number-of-dates" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code.

```
var a = '28.09.2020';
var b = '03.10.2020';

var calculateNumberOfDaysPerMonthAndYear = function(a, b) {
    function compareDatesOnBasedOfMonthAndYear(a, b) {
        if (b[2] > a[2]) return 1;
        if (b[2] < a[2]) return -1;

        if (b[1] > a[1]) return 1;
        if (b[1] < a[1]) return -1;
        return 0;
    }

    function getNextMonth(a) {
        var nextMonth = [ ...a ];
        nextMonth[1] += 1;
        if (nextMonth[1] === 13) {
            nextMonth[1] = 1;
            nextMonth[2] += 1;
        }

        return nextMonth;
    }

    var finalJson = {};
    var daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    var splittedDateA = a.split('.').map(d => parseInt(d));
    var splittedDateB = b.split('.').map(d => parseInt(d));

    var key = splittedDateA[1] + '.' + splittedDateA[2];
    finalJson[key] = daysInMonth[splittedDateA[1] - 1] + 1 - splittedDateA[0];
    if (splittedDateA[2] % 4 === 0) finalJson[key] += 1;

    var currentDate = getNextMonth(splittedDateA);
    while(compareDatesOnBasedOfMonthAndYear(currentDate, splittedDateB)) {
        key = currentDate[1] + '.' + currentDate[2];
        finalJson[key] = daysInMonth[currentDate[1] - 1];
        currentDate = getNextMonth(currentDate);
    }

    key = splittedDateB[1] + '.' + splittedDateB[2];
    finalJson[key] = splittedDateB[0];

    return finalJson;
};

console.log(calculateNumberOfDaysPerMonthAndYear(a, b));
```

The output will be a JSON object with key as the combination of month and year (eg. 8.2020) and the value will be the number of days.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

i think you could try out moment.js is a pretty nice to handle date and time.

https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/

```
    var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
    var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
    a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2019, 10, 11);

const secondDate = new Date(2019, 11, 11);

const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
```