# Javascript to count the number of days for a specific month between two dates

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.

I have specific month columns (9/30/2022, 10/31/2022,11/30/2022). I have a contract with a start date and end date (spanning multiple months).

I need to determine the number of days the contract was active for a specific month column.

Example:
Contact Start Date: 09/15/2022
Contract End Date:  10/24/2022
Number of days the contract was active in Sept 2022 is 16.

I found the code below that gives me the contract period broken down for each month (i.e.) **9 - 17; 10 - 23; **

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

I found this code

> ```
> function getDays() {
> var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("arr").value);
> var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("dep").value);
> var result = "";
> for (var year = dropdt.getFullYear(); year <= pickdt.getFullYear(); year++) {
> var firstMonth = (year == dropdt.getFullYear()) ? dropdt.getMonth() : 0;
> var lastMonth = (year == pickdt.getFullYear()) ? pickdt.getMonth() : 11;
> for (var month = firstMonth; month <= lastMonth; month++) {
> var firstDay = (year === dropdt.getFullYear() && month === firstMonth) ? dropdt.getDate() : 1;
> var lastDay = (year === pickdt.getFullYear() && month === lastMonth) ? pickdt.getDate() : 0;
> var lastDateMonth = (lastDay === 0) ? (month + 1) : month
> var firstDate = new Date(year, month, firstDay);
> var lastDate = new Date(year, lastDateMonth, lastDay);
> result += (month + 1) + " - " + parseInt((lastDate - firstDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000) + 1) + "; ";
>         }
>     }
> return result;
> }
>
> function cal() {
> if (document.getElementById("dep")) {
> document.getElementById("number-of-dates").value = getDays();
>     }
> ```

> Calculate
>   
> `

Comment: Here is the link to the original code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743975/count-the-number-of-days-per-month-between-two-dates

Comment: This question seems to lack clarity (*as a few users have assumed you want to find the number of days between two dates, but it seems you want a subset of that being the number of those days that fall within a specific month*). You stated "*I have specific month columns (9/30/2022, 10/31/2022,11/30/2022)*" but have provided no HTML or code of your own (*just code from another question/answer*). What does *your* HTML/code look like? How is the user specifying which month to see the days for that active contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet will generate an object `res` with the *keys* being zero-based month-indexes ("8" is for September, "9" for October, etc.) and the *values* are the number of days for each of these months:

```js
const start=new Date("2022-09-15");
const end=new Date("2022-11-24");
let nextFirst=new Date(start.getTime()), month, days={};
do { 
  month=nextFirst.getMonth();
  nextFirst.setMonth(month+1);nextFirst.setDate(1);
  days[month]=Math.round(((nextFirst<end?nextFirst:end)-start)/86400000);
  start.setTime(nextFirst.getTime());
} while(nextFirst<end)

console.log(days);
```

This can be extended into a more reliable function returning a year-month combination:

```js
function daysPerMonth(start,end){
 let nextFirst=new Date(start.getTime()), year, month, days={};
 do {
   year=nextFirst.getFullYear(); 
   month=nextFirst.getMonth();
   nextFirst.setMonth(month+1);nextFirst.setDate(1);   
   days[`${year}-${String(1+month).padStart(2,"0")}`]=Math.round(((nextFirst<end?nextFirst:end)-start)/86400000);
   start.setTime(nextFirst.getTime());
 } while(nextFirst<end)
 return days;
}

[["2022-09-15","2022-11-24"],["2022-11-29","2023-02-04"]].forEach(([a,b])=>
 console.log(daysPerMonth(new Date(a),new Date(b))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Managing and calculating dates, times, and date-times are notoriously finicky in javascript and across browsers. Rather than trying to define your own logic for this use the famous [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

In particular to calculate the length between two dates you can utilize the  [diff function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) between two moments

```js
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 25]);
var diff = a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

The supported measurements are years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.